# How do I solve the Visual studio 2019 'invalid profile ms_6_5' error when building a solution?

Tags: c++, shader, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, profiler

Specs are Window 10 Pro, VS 2019.16.8.3, MS DX12 shader samples.
I installed VS2019 just for this project to migrate my shader efforts into.

1>D3D12MeshletGenerator.cpp

3>dxc failed : Unknown argument: '-Qembed_debug'

2>FXC : error : invalid profile ms_6_5

This:
D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS7 comes up undefined in the cpp source file.

What is odd is I was getting file extraction errors in the standard explorer zip extraction but not in 7zip. In both cases this profile error comes and I am not sure how to fix.

I am looking at this in two ways:

Are there problems with the source files or am I missing something in the VS profile area of Visual Studio configuration or usage experience?

I hope I have included everything to make this request clear and enable expeditious recovery.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Windows 10 SDK (19041).

- `D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS7` was added to d3d12.h for this release.
- The DXIL Compiler (DXC.EXE which unfortunately Visual Studio still calls 'FXC' in the output) was updated to support amplification & mesh shaders,

To install the new SDK you need to run the **Visual Studio Installer** and then select the optional component *Windows 10 SDK (19041)*.

> For reasons I'm not privy to, it only shows up under the UWP workload and in individual components. It's not visible under the "Game Development for C++" or "Desktop development with C++".

Comment: Yep Specifically the 19041 release. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulMoore Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.